# How to convert this function to an optimized function? It should be more efficient respect to the time?

Tags: python, dictionary, optimization

I got this function which provides the user to retrieve logs that have a field with
a specific value. For instance, you can get all the logs that have john value in the
user field if you select field as getUser and set val1 as john.

These are sosme examples of the logs:

l1 = Log(int(time.mktime(time.strptime(’Mon Mar 09 12:00:00 2020’))), ’john’, 23, ’signin’, 0)

l2 = Log(int(time.mktime(time.strptime(’Mon Mar 09 14:10:00 2020’))), ’mary’, 42, ’click’, 13)

...

mylogs = [l1,l2,...]

```
def registerEqualQuery(logs, field):
    def query(val1):
        res = []
        for (index,log) in enumerate(logs):
            if getattr(log, field)() == val1:
                res.append(log)
        return res

if field not in [’getArrivaltime’,’getUser’,’getSession’,’getEvent’,’getUsrfield’]:
raise Exception(’field name not found’)
return query

q1=registerEqualQuery(mylogs,'getUser')
result = q1('john')
```

This will give me l1 as the output.

By the following operation, I can learn that how much queries I can get per second.

```
s = time.time(); result = q7(’john’); e = time.time()
1/(e-s)
```

I want to optimize this function to get more queries per second. Dictionary should be used but i don't know how to use. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

- It doesn't look like `index` is being used, so there is no need for `enumerate`
- Since the loop is building a list, it can be converted to a list comprehension, which is more performant than repeatedly calling `append` (https://leadsift.com/loop-map-list-comprehension/, https://nyu-cds.github.io/python-performance-tips/08-loops/)

Putting it altogether:

```
def registerEqualQuery(logs, field):
    def query(val1):
        return [log for log in logs if getattr(log, field)() == val1]
```